# Sending signal to user that a particular driver is loaded

Tags: linux, startup, drivers

These are some of the messages coming on console from Microzed board (Cortex A9):

```
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.603 2014] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.603 2014] xgpiops e000a000.ps7-gpio: gpio at 0xe000a000 mapped to 0xf004e000
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.603 2014] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.624 2014] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.624 2014] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.624 2014] Switching to clocksource xttcps_clocksource
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.624 2014] e0001000.serial: ttyPS0 at MMIO 0xe0001000 (irq = 82) is a xuartps
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.624 2014] console [ttyPS0] enabled
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.634 2014] xdevcfg f8007000.ps7-dev-cfg: ioremap f8007000 to f0052000 with size 100
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.662 2014] xqspips e000d000.ps7-qspi: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.662 2014] spi spi32766.0: setup: unsupported mode bits 3
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.662 2014] xqspips e000d000.ps7-qspi: can't setup spi32766.0, status -22
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.662 2014] spi_master spi32766: spi_device register error /amba@0/ps7-qspi@e000d000/ps7-qspi@0
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.662 2014] xqspips e000d000.ps7-qspi: at 0xE000D000 mapped to 0xF0054000, irq=51
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.671 2014] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.680 2014] ULPI transceiver vendor/product ID 0x0424/0x0007
```

After the line:

```
[Sat May 17 18:18:26.624 2014] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
```

I want to check that the USB driver is indeed loaded. One way I thought to see this would be to light an LED immediately after this line is printed on the console.

But how do I do this? Is there any other better way of doing this?

My main requirement is to measure the timing right from power ON until the USB driver is loaded. This can be done if I get any signal on the board the moment USB driver is loaded. I will capture this signal along with power ON, and this will give me precise information about the time USB is loaded.

This precision cannot be achieved by looking at the time stamps in log file since the messages do not come immediately and there is considerable time spent before the message start coming.

Comment: Why do you think the timestamps are inaccurate?  You should be able to do this with `udev`, BTW.

Comment: @goldilocks because time stamp is not coming exactly at the moment I am giving power. It is coming after 'some time'.

Comment: The USB driver is not loaded at exactly the moment you give power either.  A single core Cortex A9 probably takes 5-10 seconds to bootload and initialize the kernel, not including any initialization it does for itself.

Comment: @goldilocks I am interested in porecisely measuring time from power ON to USB driver loading. If I have a signal (volatge rise or fall at some pin) I can capture this and this will be most accurate info.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that what you're trying to find out is not when a driver is loaded — for example, a driver that is built into the kernel (as opposed to loaded as a module) is loaded by the bootloader. What you're trying to figure out is when the driver performs its initialization, presumably when it finishes its initialization so that peripherals that use this driver are now usable.

If you want to output some kind of visible signal when a driver has finished its initialization, you're going to have to patch the kernel. There is no general-purpose hook from userland.

If you're interested in a particular peripheral, as opposed to a “lower layer” driver such as `usbcore`, then you can udev rules. This only comes into play once the kernel has finished booting and userland (specifically udev) has started.

---

This being said, what you actually want **is** the time in the log message. In order to “measure the timing right from power ON to the USB driver loaded”, the time stamp in the log message is exactly the right information. The timestamp in the message is the time when the event happens, not the time when the log message is displayed (which can come much later, especially if the log device hasn't been initialized yet or if you're looking at the logs with the `dmesg` command).

To perform your measurement, you'll need to know the time of the power on in relation to the device's clock. If the device has no battery, so that its clock always begins at a particular origin at power on, then the elapsed time is simply the timestamp you're interested in minus the origin. If the device has a persistent clock, then first synchronize that clock with another computer (e.g. with NTP), and then measure the time of the power-on event as precisely as possible.